# knockout JS: select/dropdown is not being rendered

Tags: knockout.js

Any idea why select in the following example is not being rendered in HTML.  No error being caught, applyBindings() seems to work fine however dropdown is not displayed in html...

Here is JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    try
    {
       var mainVM = new MainViewModel();                        
       mainVM.CategoriesVm.Init(document.getElementById("divCategoriesView"));
       mainVM.CategoriesVm.BindViewModel();    
       ko.applyBindings(mainVM.CategoriesVm, mainVM.CategoriesVm.DomSection);
       alert('finished');
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        alert(err);
    }
});

function MainViewModel() {    
   var self = this;
   this.CategoriesVm = new CategoriesViewModel();    
   return self;
};

function CategoriesViewModel() {
   var self = this;

   self.$type = 'CategoriesViewModel';
   self.Categories = ko.observableArray();
   self.selectedCategory = ko.observable();
   self.DomSection = null;

   this.Init = function (domSectionElement) {
    self.DomSection = domSectionElement;
   };

var GetJsObject = function (obj) {
    if (obj && ObjectTypeChecker.IsJsonObject(obj)) {
        obj = $.parseJSON(obj);
    }

    if (obj && obj.d) {
        obj = eval(obj.d);
    }

    return obj;
};   

this.BindViewModel = function (jsonCategories) {
    try {
        var data = [{
            CategoryID: 1,
            CategoryName: "red"
        }];
        self.Categories(data);

        ko.mapping.fromJS(self.Categories, self);
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
  };

};
```

And here is HTML:

```
<div id="divMainView">
    <div id="divCategoriesView" data-bind="with: MainViewModel.CategoriesViewModel">
        <select ID="ddlProductCategory" data-bind="options: Categories, optionsValue: CategoryID, optionsText: CategoryName, value: selectedCategory">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dQ3uW/

```
<select ID="ddlProductCategory" data-bind="options: Categories, optionsValue: function(item){ return item.CategoryID; }, optionsText: function(item){ return item.CategoryName; }, value: selectedCategory">
</select>
```

I don't understand this block of code

```
data-bind="with: MainViewModel.CategoriesViewModel"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, mdcuesta. Since I have nested view model construct I am trying to bind select to the child's viewmodel property (Categories), and I thought that data-bind="with: MainViewModel.CategoriesViewModel" should set the binding context to the inner (child) viewmodel. Here is the example for "with" construct: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html
Also, from knockout site tutorials it looks like you can bind select options without any  javascript functions inside data-bind construct.  Is it not possible?

Comment: Here is the link to options tutorial from knockout JS site: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html
or http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html

Answer (score 0):

I did resolve the problem with the structure I want.  However it looks like the root viewmodel has to **be created and assigned to global context variable**;  I do not think that this is particularly good idea but please let me know if there is any other way to resolve this...

Here is final code.
HTML:

```
<div id="divMainView">
    <div id="divCategoriesView" data-bind="with: mainVM.CategoriesVm">
        <select ID="ddlProductCategory" data-bind='options: Categories, optionsValue: "CategoryID", optionsText: "CategoryName", value: "selectedCategory"'>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    mainVM = new MainViewModel();   
    $(document).ready(function () {
    try
    {                              
       mainVM.CategoriesVm.Init(document.getElementById("divCategoriesView"));
       mainVM.CategoriesVm.BindViewModel();    
       ko.applyBindings(mainVM.CategoriesVm, mainVM.CategoriesVm.DomSection)
       alert('finished');
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        alert(err);
    }
});

function MainViewModel() {    
   var self = this;
   this.CategoriesVm = new CategoriesViewModel();    
   return self;
};

function CategoriesViewModel() {
   var self = this;

   self.$type = 'CategoriesViewModel';
   self.Categories = ko.observableArray();
   self.selectedCategory = ko.observable();
   self.DomSection = null;

   self.Init = function (domSectionElement) {
    self.DomSection = domSectionElement;
   };


    var GetJsObject = function (obj) {
        if (obj && ObjectTypeChecker.IsJsonObject(obj)) {
            obj = $.parseJSON(obj);
        }

        if (obj && obj.d) {
            obj = eval(obj.d);
        }

        return obj;
    };   

    this.BindViewModel = function (jsonCategories) {
        try {
            var data = [{
                    CategoryID: 1,
                    CategoryName: "red"
                },
                {
                    CategoryID: 2,
                    CategoryName: "blue"}];
            self.Categories(data);

            ko.mapping.fromJS(self.Categories, self);
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
  };

};
```